# Xamarin: Tableview rowheight not working for custom viewcell in android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am working on Xamarin.Forms app with few `TableView` that has custom `ViewCell`.

In PCL:

```
public class MyViewCell : ViewCell
{
   public static readonly BindableProperty NoTapProperty =
          BindableProperty.Create("NoTap", typeof(bool), typeof(CheckedTextCell), defaultValue: false);

   public bool NoTap
   {
      get { return (bool)GetValue(NoTapProperty); }
      set { SetValue(NoTapProperty, value); }
   }
}
```

In iOS:

```
public class MyViewCellRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
{
   UITableViewCell _nativeCell;

   public override UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UITableViewCell reusableCell, UITableView tv)
   {
      _nativeCell = base.GetCell(item, reusableCell, tv);
      var formsCell = item as MyViewCell;

      if (formsCell != null)
      {
          formsCell.PropertyChanged -= OnPropertyChanged;
          formsCell.PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged;
       }
       SetTap(formsCell);
       return _nativeCell;
    }

    void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       var formsCell = sender as MyViewCell;
       if (formsCell == null) return;
       if (e.PropertyName == MyViewCell.NoTapProperty.PropertyName)
       {
          SetTap(formsCell);
        }
     }

     void SetTap(MyViewCell formsCell)
     {
        if (formsCell.NoTap) _nativeCell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;
        else _nativeCell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.Default;
      }
}
```

In Android:

```
public class MyViewCellRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
{
   Android.Views.View _nativeCell;

   protected override Android.Views.View GetCellCore(Cell item, Android.Views.View convertView, Android.Views.ViewGroup parent, Android.Content.Context context)
   {
       _nativeCell = base.GetCellCore(item, convertView, parent, context);

       var formsCell = item as MyViewCell;

       if (formsCell != null)
       {
          formsCell.PropertyChanged -= OnPropertyChanged;
          formsCell.PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged;
       }

       SetTap(formsCell);
       return _nativeCell;
   }

   void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   {
      var formsCell = sender as MyViewCell;
      if (formsCell == null) return;

      if (e.PropertyName == MyViewCell.NoTapProperty.PropertyName)
      { SetTap(formsCell); }
   }

   void SetTap(MyViewCell formsCell)
   {
      if (formsCell == null) return;
      _nativeCell.Clickable = formsCell.NoTap;
    }
}
```

Then I used it in XAML like the following:

```
<TableView Intent="Settings" RowHeight="50" HasUnevenRows="true">
   <TableView.Root>
      <TableSection>
         <local:MyViewCell NoTap="true" Height="70">
            <!-- More codes here -->
         </local:MyViewCell>
      </TableSection>
      <TableSection Title="Study Mode">
         <local:MyViewCell NoTap="true">
            <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="20, 0">
               <Label Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle}" YAlign="Center" Text="Phrase Display" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
               <!-- More code for segmented control -->
            </Grid>
         </local:MyViewCell>
         <local:MyViewCell x:Name="btn" NoTap="true">
            <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="20, 0">
               <!-- More codes here -->
             </Grid>
         </local:MyViewCell>
      </TableSection>
   </TableView.Root>
</TableView>
```

The `RowHeight="50"` is perfectly working in iOS (meaning all the table rows have the same height). Unfortunately, that is not the case in Android. Please see the images below.

Android:

[image]

iOS:
[image]

Anyone knows what I'm missing?

Comment: Probably the `HasUnevenRows` is getting been handled on different ways between platforms. Maybe the android is obeying it prior to `HeightRequest`. Did you try to take off the HasUnevenRows property from XAML?

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza somehow this works but the problem is I have one `TableSection` with a different height that I forgot to include. Will edit my code

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [Padding](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/margin-and-padding/) to control the element's rendering position. In your `Grid` view, modify your `Padding` from `"20, 0"` to `"20, 10, 0, 10"`.

Here is my code:

```
<TableView Intent="Settings" RowHeight="50" HasUnevenRows="true">
    <TableView.Root>
        <TableSection >
            <local:MyViewCell NoTap="true" Height="70" >
                <!-- More codes here -->
                <Label  YAlign="Center" Text="Phrase Display" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
            </local:MyViewCell>
        </TableSection>
        <TableSection Title="Study Mode">
            <local:MyViewCell NoTap="true">
                <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="20, 10, 0, 10">
                    <Label  YAlign="Center" Text="Phrase Display" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
                    <!-- More code for segmented control -->
                </Grid>
            </local:MyViewCell>
            <local:MyViewCell x:Name="btn" NoTap="true">
                <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="20, 10, 0, 10">
                    <!-- More codes here -->
                     <StackLayout>
                        <Label  YAlign="Center" Text="Phrase Display" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
                        <Label  YAlign="Center" Text="Phrase Display" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
                        <Label  YAlign="Center" Text="Phrase Display" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
                    </StackLayout>
                 </Grid>
            </local:MyViewCell>
        </TableSection>
    </TableView.Root>
</TableView>
```

[Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABZUs.png) when using `"20, 0"` as your `Grid` `Padding`.

[Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMaxj.png)  when using `"20, 10, 0, 10"` as your `Grid` `Padding`.